# Making a dynamic array in vbscript whose values are preserved

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

What I want is an array which would store all the ID values coming from the database.How to do the same?

Comment: Can you fetch value from database. If it is post some codes what you've tried

Comment: Please provide more information. How exactly are the values "coming from the database"? What do you want to do with the values once you retrieved them from the database?

Answer (score 2):

This is a task for the [ADO GetRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method

```
<%
Dim aRs, oConn, oRS, sSQL
Set oConn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Provider = Application("Provider")
oConn.Open Application("Database"), Application("UserName"), Application("Password")
sSQL="SELECT ID FROM yourtable ORDER by ID"
Set oRS = oConn.Execute(sSQL)
if not oRS.eof then
        aRS=oRS.GetRows()
end if
oRS.close
oConn.close
%>
```